# How could I use threading to run this subprogram alongside my main code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, tkinter

### code i need to run along side my main code

```
def check():
    if running == True:
        if FourInRow == True:          
            running == False
        else:
            print("A")
            window.after(100, check)
```

I have tried making a threading class but I cant get it to work.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Minimal complete example please, but it might be as simple as `running = False` that you need

Comment: Sorry i meant threading! I need this code to be constantly running alongside my maincode and I've found out the way to do this is using multithreading but I just can't get it to work.

Comment: Show what you tried to make it work, and what happened.  You don't need to create a threading class.

Answer (score 1):

First, you're missing a `global` statement (as you wish to change the global `running`) and have incorrect `==` vs. `=` syntax:

```
def check():
    global running

    if running:
        if FourInRow:          
            running = False
        else:
            print("A")
            window.after(100, check)
```

Second, you don't need threading as `window.after(...)` will keep this code repeating as long as `running` is `True` and `FourInRow` isn't `True`.  If you need it to run beyond that, outdent the `window.after(...)` statement as much as needed.  You can initiate this timed event by calling `check()` at the top level of your code, just before you turn over control to the tkinter event loop.